# When interchanging Enterprise Architect Diagrams the Lines disappear

Tags: import, enterprise-architect

I am trying to import Diagrams from EA version 10.1 to another EA with version 12.1.

I have tried various import methods: XMI, Package control etc. The import works, but the connecting lines between components disappear when transporting.

Both EA-Files share the same Design Repositories and import Objects with links from there.

EDIT: I am currently working with component diagram and want to show the information flow relations between components. The diagrams are connecting component objects originating in other packages. (Different branches inside the model)

Comment: This leaves just room for speculation without knowing what is in the XMI. Which are the "lines" that disappear and how do you recognize it?

Comment: If you mean "Messages" with "Lines" I know the answer.

Comment: @THomas Yes i mean the information flow between objects. I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Still I have just a guess, but it's a good guess. Messages can only be exchanged between objects. So in sequence diagrams (and I guess in communication diagrams) you need instances rather than classes. When you transfer such a diagram via XMI it will not work without instances. This information is rather well hidden somewhere in the help (don't ask me where, but I know it's there).

I think it's a flaw in EA to allow message transfer between classes in first place. But hey, this is EA...